# React Native (Intent Redirection fix): What's the equivalent of getCallingActivity() to check for malicious redirection?

Tags: android, google-play, react-native, android-security

We were asked to make changes to our react native app when an updated version was submitted to Google Play Store. The issue highlighted was "Intent Redirection" vulnerability. It was legacy code, but nevertheless, better late than never.

One of the suggested methods in the Google help [guide](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en) was this:

> Option 2: Ensure that the extracted Intent is from a trustworthy source.
>
> You can verify that the originating Activity can be trusted using methods like >getCallingActivity. For example:

```
 // check if the originating Activity is from trusted package
 if (getCallingActivity().getPackageName().equals(“known”)) {
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   // extract the nested Intent
   Intent forward = (Intent) intent.getParcelableExtra(“key”);
   // redirect the nested Intent
   startActivity(forward);
 }
```

On changing code as per this guidance, the build showed an error that `getCallingActivity` was not a known symbol. The code already uses `getCurrentActivity` and `getApplicationContext`.

What would be the best way for us to rectify in our React Native app, this vulnerability in our native Java code?

**Will deeply appreciate your quick support here. Thanks!**

Comment: Same issue for me. Did you find the solution deetho?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue? :( looking for solution

Comment: Did you find any solution @RameshKumar?

Comment: No @SudeepKumar. I encountered this issue for using rezorpay react native module. Waiting for the new release from them.

Comment: No luck so far, @SudeepKumar

Comment: @RameshKumar, do share an update if you get a revert from Razorpay.

Comment: Did any one got it fixed ? im stuck with this issue too :(

Comment: I have the same problem, do not know which react-native dependency in package.json causes this. Is there a way to find out? I do not use RazorPay. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RazorPay released a new version. Please follow below link for more info.

> https://github.com/razorpay/react-native-razorpay/issues/291

Answer (score 0):

We had to upgrade our [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share) dependency. In the releases it mentions some security patches a little while back. Once we upgraded to 4.x, we stopped receiving emails from google regarding the security vulnerability.

Answer (score -1):

Can you Try Reading this Document ?
https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//about/appsecurity/play-rewards/Android_app_vulnerability_classes.pdf